# We have Integrated ADB2C with a web application to handle a user signup & authentication, need help to add a customization in B2C signup form

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

Here is a question from the ADB2C Signup page. Where I have an use case to add more validation in the B2C SignUp form, we have to restrict / show an error if the user types in an invalid phone number using all 9’s or all ten digit phone number shouldn’t be the same as 1111111111 / 9999999999 in the telephone number field. Here we are using B2C custom policies to handle these user flow activities. Please suggest us if there a work around to handle this scenario.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [predicate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/predicates#predicate-methods) to perform validations. Regex validation may suffice.

Otherwise, you will need to use front end [javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) to apply the validations you desire.